# Possible formula for $ f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{-n!} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, factorial

I was wondering if we have a formula for the following function:

$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{x^{0!}} + \frac{1}{x^{1!}} + \frac{1}{x^{2!}} + \frac{1}{x^{3!}} + ... = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{-n!}
$$

(Like we have for the geometric series):

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^{-k} =\frac{1}{1-x}
$$

Or even if we have nice values for similar functions (infinite sums that has factorials in the exponents) or if we can evaluete any value of f(x) like: $$f(e),f(2)...$$

Comment: No hope even using special functions (I am afraid).

Comment: Your function is a good example of a function with a natural boundary on the unit circle in the complex plane.  In that regard, it is completely unlike the geometric series.

Comment: regardless that there is no closed form solution, it might be interesting to consider the limiting behaviour as $x\rightarrow 0 ,1_-$